# "dotnet run" do not run the program

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I created a project in VS Code with "dotnet new console" and I am trying to run C# console program using "dotnet run" in project folder, but process ends, without errors (there is no console output). How can i run it?

There is the Visual Studio Code output data:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 22.12.2021, 20:19:13
    Target: path/to/project

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: /home/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.17/.omnisharp/1.37.17/run
    PID: 18538

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on ubuntu 20.4 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Checking the 'DOTNET_ROOT' environment variable to find a .NET SDK
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Using the 'dotnet' on the PATH.
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: StandAlone 17.0.0 - "/home/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.17/.omnisharp/1.37.17/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to '/home/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.17/.omnisharp/1.37.17/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 17.0.0 - "/home/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.17/.omnisharp/1.37.17/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
            MSBuildToolsPath = /home/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.17/.omnisharp/1.37.17/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin
            CscToolPath = /home/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.17/.omnisharp/1.37.17/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Roslyn
            BypassFrameworkInstallChecks = true
            MSBuildExtensionsPath = /home/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.17/.omnisharp/1.37.17/omnisharp/.msbuild
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.ImplementTypeWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 110
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.BlockStructureWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 140
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in 'path/to/project'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        No solution files found in 'path/to/project'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'path/to/project/TestProj.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in 'path/to/project'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location 'path/to/project' on host 18032.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: path/to/project/TestProj.csproj
It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
Install a .NET SDK from:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file 'path/to/project/TestProj.csproj'.
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.  path/to/project/TestProj.csproj
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject (System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName, Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, System.Object[] args) [0x00040] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.VerifyThrowInvalidProject[T1] (System.Boolean condition, System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName, Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00003] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject[T1] (Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00000] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement]& projects, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult, System.Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError) [0x00348] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImports (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult) [0x00027] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].EvaluateImportElement (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement) [0x0000d] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].PerformDepthFirstPass (Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport) [0x000e6] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate () [0x0013b] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IEvaluatorData`4[P,I,M,D] data, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement root, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, System.Int32 maxNodeCount, Microsoft.Build.Collections.PropertyDictionary`1[T] environmentProperties, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingService, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IItemFactory`2[S,T] itemFactory, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IToolsetProvider toolsetProvider, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectRootElementCacheBase projectRootElementCache, Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildEventContext buildEventContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, System.Int32 submissionId, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext, System.Boolean interactive) [0x00047] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.Reevaluate (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00063] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00035] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00000] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00007] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.Initialize (System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00127] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00073] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings) [0x00000] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings) [0x00000] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection) [0x00000] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject (System.String fileName, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion) [0x000f7] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject (System.String fileName, System.String toolsVersion) [0x00000] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore (System.String filePath, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] projectConfigurationsInSolution) [0x00160] in <8b2689abe3ed4288800a3ed0bb7e78a5>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject (System.String filePath, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] configurationsInSolution) [0x0000d] in <8b2689abe3ed4288800a3ed0bb7e78a5>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load (System.String filePath, OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader loader, System.Guid sessionId, OmniSharp.Services.DotNetInfo dotNetInfo) [0x00023] in <8b2689abe3ed4288800a3ed0bb7e78a5>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager+<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<LoadProject>b__0 () [0x00000] in <8b2689abe3ed4288800a3ed0bb7e78a5>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Func`1[System.ValueTuple`3[OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo,System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1[OmniSharp.MSBuild.Logging.MSBuildDiagnostic],OmniSharp.MSBuild.Notification.ProjectLoadedEventArgs]].invoke_TResult()
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject (System.String projectFilePath, System.Func`1[TResult] loader) [0x0001b] in <8b2689abe3ed4288800a3ed0bb7e78a5>:0 
path/to/project/TestProj.csproj(0,0)
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.  path/to/project/TestProj.csproj
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject (System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName, Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, System.Object[] args) [0x00040] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.VerifyThrowInvalidProject[T1] (System.Boolean condition, System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName, Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00003] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject[T1] (Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00000] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement]& projects, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult, System.Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError) [0x00348] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImports (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult) [0x00027] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].EvaluateImportElement (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement) [0x0000d] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].PerformDepthFirstPass (Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport) [0x000e6] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate () [0x0013b] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IEvaluatorData`4[P,I,M,D] data, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement root, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, System.Int32 maxNodeCount, Microsoft.Build.Collections.PropertyDictionary`1[T] environmentProperties, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingService, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IItemFactory`2[S,T] itemFactory, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IToolsetProvider toolsetProvider, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectRootElementCacheBase projectRootElementCache, Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildEventContext buildEventContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, System.Int32 submissionId, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext, System.Boolean interactive) [0x00047] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.Reevaluate (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00063] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00035] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00000] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00007] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.Initialize (System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00127] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00073] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings) [0x00000] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings) [0x00000] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection) [0x00000] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject (System.String fileName, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion) [0x000f7] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject (System.String fileName, System.String toolsVersion) [0x00000] in <9adaf83a4a1e41c79c53523270b5b9b8>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore (System.String filePath, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] projectConfigurationsInSolution) [0x00160] in <8b2689abe3ed4288800a3ed0bb7e78a5>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject (System.String filePath, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] configurationsInSolution) [0x0000d] in <8b2689abe3ed4288800a3ed0bb7e78a5>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load (System.String filePath, OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader loader, System.Guid sessionId, OmniSharp.Services.DotNetInfo dotNetInfo) [0x00023] in <8b2689abe3ed4288800a3ed0bb7e78a5>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager+<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<LoadProject>b__0 () [0x00000] in <8b2689abe3ed4288800a3ed0bb7e78a5>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Func`1[System.ValueTuple`3[OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo,System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1[OmniSharp.MSBuild.Logging.MSBuildDiagnostic],OmniSharp.MSBuild.Notification.ProjectLoadedEventArgs]].invoke_TResult()
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject (System.String projectFilePath, System.Func`1[TResult] loader) [0x0001b] in <8b2689abe3ed4288800a3ed0bb7e78a5>:0 

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: path/to/project/TestProj.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.OmniSharpWorkspace
        Miscellaneous file: path/to/project/obj/Debug/net6.0/TestProj.GlobalUsings.g.cs added to workspace
[info]: OmniSharp.OmniSharpWorkspace
        Miscellaneous file: path/to/project/obj/Debug/net6.0/TestProj.AssemblyInfo.cs added to workspace
[info]: OmniSharp.OmniSharpWorkspace
        Miscellaneous file: path/to/project/obj/Debug/net6.0/.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs added to workspace
```

OS: Ubuntu 20.04;
Dotnet version: 6.0.101;

Comment: Did you notice this `The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.`?

Comment: Run the command `dotnet --list-sdks`, what do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install NET SDK's

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu

You can follow this link to find how to install in your distribution. I recommend install NET 6 version ( dotnet-sdk-6.0)